# Linux ARM Abort oops from user space

Tags: linux, arm

On a ARM Cortex-A9 (Freescale iMX6SL) running Linux kernel 3.0.35, I am seeing a kernel oops with PC and LR (0x402aca32/0x402ac3cd) that is in user space. Mode is USER_32 and ISA is Thumb. There is no code on this system that executes in Thumb mode.

```
[  597.195954] Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address 000a34d4
[  597.205436] pgd = c35dc000
[  597.208149] [000a34d4] *pgd=8c454831, *pte=8374c1cf, *ppte=8374ca3e
[  597.214657] Internal error: Oops: 81f [#1] PREEMPT
[  597.219609] Modules linked in: ...<snip>...
[  597.243075] CPU: 0    Tainted: P        W    (3.0.35-aaaaaa #1)
[  597.249162] PC is at 0x402aca32
[  597.252304] LR is at 0x402ac3cd
[  597.255448] pc : [<402aca32>]    lr : [<402ac3cd>]    psr: 60000030
[  597.255453] sp : be8fc220  ip : 00000000  fp : 00000809
[  597.266940] r10: 00000004  r9 : 40336ea0  r8 : 00000818
[  597.272168] r7 : 4034c25c  r6 : 00011b31  r5 : 00001250  r4 : 000a2cc8
[  597.278698] r3 : 00000000  r2 : 000a34d0  r1 : 00011b30  r0 : 00000809
[  597.285229] Flags: nZCv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode USER_32  ISA Thumb  Segment user
[  597.292629] Control: 10c53c7d  Table: 835dc059  DAC: 00000015
[  597.298378] Process wancontrol (pid: 7551, stack limit = 0xce9f02e8)
[  597.307890] ---[ end trace f50414d2a3d239df ]---
[  597.312516] Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt
[  597.325257] Backtrace: 
[  597.327567] [<c0135248>] (dump_backtrace+0x0/0x110) from [<c041e188>] (dump_stack+0x18/0x1c)
[  597.336837]  r6:c3088d20 r5:ce9f02e8 r4:c0537b48 r3:00000002
[  597.342382] [<c041e170>] (dump_stack+0x0/0x1c) from [<c041e200>] (panic+0x74/0x194)
[  597.350794] [<c041e18c>] (panic+0x0/0x194) from [<c01355b0>] (die+0x1a4/0x1e4)
[  597.358402]  r3:07ffff00 r2:ce9f1db8 r1:c0537f90 r0:c04ac8ba
[  597.364044]  r7:00000000
[  597.366591] [<c013540c>] (die+0x0/0x1e4) from [<c013a7b0>] (__do_kernel_fault+0x6c/0x8c)
[  597.375465]  r8:00000000 r7:ce9f1fb0 r6:cee35900 r5:0000081f r4:000a34d4
[  597.382060] [<c013a744>] (__do_kernel_fault+0x0/0x8c) from [<c013aa90>] (do_page_fault+0x2c0/0x2f0)
[  597.391760]  r8:cee35900 r7:000a34d4 r6:c3088d20 r5:ce9f1fb0 r4:00000001
[  597.398438] r3:ce9f1fb0
[  597.400909] [<c013a7d0>] (do_page_fault+0x0/0x2f0) from [<c012c1b8>] (do_DataAbort+0x38/0xa0)
[  597.410178] [<c012c180>] (do_DataAbort+0x0/0xa0) from [<c0131a88>] (ret_from_exception+0x0/0x10)
[  597.419298] Exception stack(0xce9f1fb0 to 0xce9f1ff8)
[  597.424664] 1fa0:                                     00000809 00011b30 000a34d0 00000000
[  597.434300] 1fc0: 000a2cc8 00001250 00011b31 4034c25c 00000818 40336ea0 00000004 00000809
[  597.442488] 1fe0: 00000000 be8fc220 402ac3cd 402aca32 60000030 ffffffff
[  597.455455]  r8:00000818 r7:4034c25c r6:00011b31 r5:0000000f r4:0000040f
```

If code was executing in user space, it should get SEGV.

```
void arm_notify_die(const char *str, struct pt_regs *regs,
        struct siginfo *info, unsigned long err, unsigned long trap)
{
    if (user_mode(regs)) {
        current->thread.error_code = err;
        current->thread.trap_no = trap;

        force_sig_info(info->si_signo, info, current);
    } else {
        die(str, regs, err);
    }
}
```

Why does it go into die()?

This happens repeatedly with the same backtrace for the same address 0x000a34d4. I can't say the stack has been hosed because the values look the same in different instances of this kernel oops.

Comment: Looks like the registers didn't come from userspace (or the structure is corrupted).

Comment: You have several exceptions happening at the same time.  See: *end trace f50414d2a3d239df*.  So you may get a `SIGSEGV`, but you are also getting a kernel crash and it will call `die()`.